# How to hide chessboard in a spoiler tag

Tags: feature-request

I'd like to respond to [How to visualize a position](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/12678/how-to-visualize-a-position) by showing a series of moves in algebraic notation, then the board at the point in the game, but hidden in a spoiler tag. This is with the aim of showing a training exercise where the OP can test their visualisation skills compared to the board.

It seems not possible at the moment, so maybe it can be realized as a new feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can upload an image of the board and hide it in a spoiler tag:

`>! ![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLd01.png)`

produces

> [image]

I don't think it is possible to hide the PGN player in a spoiler tag.

EDIT: I see now that you have used this solution yourself already.